# duplicate symbol using google play games services(with cocos2d-x)

Tags: cocos2d-x, google-play-games

it occured clang error

```
duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_num_locks in:
/proj.ios/frameworks/gpg.framework/gpg(libgpg.a-i386-master.o)
/libs/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o)
duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_set_dynlock_create_callback in:
/proj.ios/frameworks/gpg.framework/gpg(libgpg.a-i386-master.o)
/libs/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o)
duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_set_dynlock_lock_callback in:
/proj.ios/frameworks/gpg.framework/gpg(libgpg.a-i386-master.o)
/libs/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o)
duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_set_dynlock_destroy_callback in:
/proj.ios/frameworks/gpg.framework/gpg(libgpg.a-i386-master.o)
/libs/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o)
duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_set_locking_callback in:
/proj.ios/frameworks/gpg.framework/gpg(libgpg.a-i386-master.o)
/libs/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o)
```

Because...
Google play games services include openssl module, but it is partially.
Cocos2d-x demand method(openssl) is not include in Google play games services.
So google play games services and openssl conflict module.

Are you here solving this problem?

Comment: Which version of the Google Play Games Services SDK Is this for Android or iOS?

Comment: Google Play Games Services SDK is iOS ver, version is 5.1.1

Comment: it occured at ios simulator environment.